# Encrypting DropBox file using Android DropBox API

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I have got the direction creation and file upload working in android using the dropbox api. The file I want to store can contain personal information for synchronisation purposes between the phone and drop box.

Due to this, is it possible to encrypt the file or have I have I just got to encrypt the data before it is submitted into dropbox.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2):

You can and you should obfuscate your code so people won't see your app and secret keys. You can do so by yourself or use some help from **ProGuard** or **JBCO**.

I have never tried JBCO, but i know PrGuard can do obfuscation and sometimes some code optimization.

JBCO which stands for Java ByteCode Obfuscation is a bit more agressive and does some bytecode obfuscation. It's really hard to read.